# Remove row change next all row id in table jquery

Tags: php, jquery, yii, cgridview

Im using  [yii-editable-grid](https://github.com/SiZEg/yii-editable-grid)

Example:

```
<tbody>
    <tr id='0'> <td>Row 1</td> <td>Delete</td></tr>
    <tr id='1'> <td>Row 2</td> <td>Delete</td></tr>
    <tr id='2'> <td>Row 3</td> <td>Delete</td></tr>
    <tr id='3'> <td>Row 4</td> <td>Delete</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

When Delete Row 2 should change the ID of next row in a table

```
<tbody>
      <tr id='0'> <td>Row 1</td> </tr>      
      <tr id='1'> <td>Row 3</td> </tr>
      <tr id='2'> <td>Row 4</td> </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Please anyone help to resolve this ?

Comment: And how, exactly, are you deleting these rows?

Comment: Delete by button in Every row

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("tr").click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
    $("tr").prop("id", function () {
        return $(this).index();

    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xtz111q3/7/)**

use **[nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)**, to stop unwanted changes

```
$("tr").click(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    $(this).nextAll("tr").prop("id", function () {
        return id++;
    });
    $(this).remove();

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xtz111q3/8/)**